# Android build fails string/activity_name) not found

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor, ionic5

My Ionic5 + Capacitor build is failing on android with the error below. If I google I find similar errors that are related to `fb_app` settings. I think the android project is misconfigured.
Is it this line in the config below:

```
android:label="@string/activity_name"
```

What shall I look for to debug this?

```
android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/build/intermediates/library_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:50:9-56:58: AAPT: error: resource string/activity_name (aka APP_NAME:string/activity_name) not found.
```

Here is named file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="capacitor.android.plugins"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="29" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application>
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="$ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled"
            android:value="$AUTOMATIC_SCREEN_REPORTING_ENABLED" />

        <receiver
            android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <provider
            android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.sharing.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/sharing_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name="com.keyes.youtube.OpenYouTubePlayerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.bunkerpalace.cordova.YouTubeActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:label="@string/activity_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

all works well for iOS btw.

Comment: check activity_name.xml file if available.

Comment: `find ./android -name 'activity_name.xml'` is empty... ?

Answer (score 4):

in android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml replace @string/activity_name with your any name

assuming you are using capacitor.

Comment: Yes, using capacitor. In your response - you mean 'any name' or 'app name'? Typo?

Comment: any name, app name will do too

Comment: Here's also a few solutions here too: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-build-fails-string-activity-name-not-found/200866

Comment: Further to my comment... just replace this: '@string/activity_name' with this: '@string/app_name'

Answer (score 1):

go to res/values/strings.xml
just add this :
  your_name